# Anomaly in switching windows on different viewports in Unity

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, ccsm, unity-tweak-tool

My sample setting is as follows:

Viewport1 contains following window:

- Firefox A

Viewport2 contains following windows:

- Firefox B
- Gedit

When Viewport1 is shown and Firefox A has gained focus after Gedit, I can switch to Gedit via a single key stroke <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

However, after I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> again, Firefox B is switched. How can I achieve to switch to Firefox A without extra key stroke?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Unity.

**Edit 1:** `Bias alt-tab to prefer windows on the current viewport` of ccsm conflicts with `Switch between windows on all workspaces` of Unity Tweak tool. Is `Bias alt-tab to prefer windows on the current viewport` of ccsm  rendered to be useless?

Answer (score 2):

From CCSM (install the `compizconfig-settings-manager` package if you don't have it):

Ubuntu Unity Plugin → Switcher → Uncheck "Bias alt-tab to prefer windows on the current viewport"

Comment: I have tried your solution, however it does not work.